# Android NDK. 'abs' was not declared in this scope

Tags: android, c++11, android-ndk

Cant build with using gnustl_static. Got:

```
'abs' was not declared in this scope
```

And when trying to build with stlport I cant use c++11 methods.
Here is my Application.mk:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11 -w
APP_PLATFORM := android-19
APP_OPTIM := release
```

And Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := ModuleName
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lm -llog -landroid
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := .......
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += .......
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: did you try #include <cmath> and std::abs ?

Comment: Hi, stijn. Yes it works. But I want to compile sources without modifying them. Is it possible?

Comment: maybe with the correct build options - check with the author of the sources you have? Surely they have specified how to use/build them? Maybe file a bug report if you think it's a bug that you can't compile their source?